# How does one find $P(T\le a)$ where $T\sim t(n-2)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I think I've done this before, but I'm still feeling confused as to how this thing works. Namely, what does it mean when it is asked to find $P(T\le a)$ where $T\sim t(n-2)$?

So, $T$ is a random variable from the Student T distribution. $P$ uses the normal distribution to find a value. Now, how do I combine both and what exactly does it mean?

For example, I want to find $P(-a\le T \le a)=0.500895$ (that is, find $a$), where $T\sim t(16)$. How do I do so? This must be simple, but when it comes to statistics, I often feel quite confused.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) you can find the PDF. If this PDF is denoted by $f$ then e.g. $P(T<a)=\int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx$ and $P(-a\leq T\leq a)=\int_{-a}^af(x)dx$

Comment: @drhab I used the t table in that article but it's not clear how to determine a in $P(|T|\le a)=0.5$, since there is no such value as 0.5 in the table. Can you please let me know what command would you use in R?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I overlooked that you were looking for $a$ so misinterpreted your question. My comment is an answer to the question in your title. Further I dislike tables and that sort of things. As soon as I could I run away from statistics to end up at probability theory :-).

Comment: @drhab I found $a\approx 0.002$, but I think the value is incorrect, judging by what I see when I try to build a prediction interval.

Comment: If $\nu=16$ then I find $P(-0.69<T<0.69)=0.5$ in the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Table_of_selected_values).

Comment: Thanks. This seems closed to the truth, judging by the prediction interval that I got :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use R to solve for $\alpha$ in $P(-\alpha < T < \alpha) = .6,$ where 
$T \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu = 16).$

By symmetry, $P(-\alpha < T < \alpha) = .6$ implies $P(T < - \alpha) = .2.$
Then in R:

```
qt(.2, 16)                    ## 'qt' is quantile fcn (inverse CDF)
##  -0.864667
alp = -qt(.2, 16);  alp
## 0.864667                   ## required value of alpha
diff(pt(c(-alp, alp), 16))
## 0.6                        ## using CDF for verification
```

The plot below shows the density function of $\mathsf{T}(16)$ and
the vertical dotted lines are at $\pm \alpha,$ with probability $0.2$
in each 'tail'.

[image]

Similarly, for $P(-\alpha < T < \alpha) = .5.$